# List with read and unread status drawable adding to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, view, baseadapter

Am able to display list with data but coming to read and unread i need to add one draw able icon to the list item.Am able to get data from the source and with the help of base adapter  based on the status flag for read and unread am able to add icon to the list view then after when i scroll the list the data is changes automatically please provide some help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the specific decoration of an item in `getView` method of the list `adapter`. Then just refresh it via `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` so the `listview` will refresh its views based on adapter data.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the visible state of the `View` containing the read icon based on the read state. You should set this within the `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method of the adaptor.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

This implementation calls for having a separate list of Read Items.Initially all items will be unread in this case the readList = "" ;

Next in your adapters onClick method, you will get position of the clicked view. Based on this position, you must get the ID of the element that you have used to populate the list view. That element can have this structure: [ID,Name,URL,Image]. On getting the corresponding ID to the tapped position in the listView, save it to readList as readList = "12//".

On next tap of the list view, get corrosponding ID of the element, check if the ID already exists in the readList. If it exists, do nothing. Or if it does not exist in the readList, add it to readList so that readList= "12//34//"

Now you have managed to get the IDs of the read elements, next you need to mark them as read in your list View. For that, in your grtView Method of the adapter, get the ID corresponding to the Positon. Then check if this ID exists in the readList.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to place both read and unread icons based on the status toggle the read and unread icons.

```
in the adapter class do like this:

 if (getAllRequestsAL.get(position).getAType().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
    holder.request_type_Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
    } else {
    holder.request_type_Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
    }
```